# Eigenvalues of $M A M^T$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ and $M$ be two real $n \times n$ matrices, with $A$ symmetric and $M$ invertible. I know that the eigenvalues of $A$ and of $MAM^{-1}$ are the same. What can we say about the eigenvalues of $MAM^{T}$, where $M^T$ is the transpose of $M$? I worked out an example and found out that they can be different, so I wonder if at least some estimate can be made.

Comment: If $M$ were orthogonal we'd have the same eigenvalues. Not sure in general.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia